# Input verification error message is not working

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, delphi-11-alexandria

I am trying to create a procedure that shows an error message if the input doesn't match the condition.

Here is my code:

```
procedure TForm_Main.Input(Edit: TEdit; I: Integer);
var
  Error_Text: TLabel;
begin
  if (Assigned(Error_Text)) then
  begin
    Error_Text.Text := '';
    Error_Text.Visible := False;
  end
  else
  begin
    Error_Text := TLabel.Create(Edit);
    Error_Text.Parent := Edit;
    Error_Text.TextSettings.FontColor := TAlphaColors.Red;
    Error_Text.Position.Y := 25;
    Error_Text.AutoSize := True;
    Error_Text.Visible := False;
  end;

  if Edit.Text.IsEmpty then
  begin
    Error_Text.Text := '';
    Error_Text.Visible := False;
  end
  else
  begin
    case I of
      1:
        begin
          if not TRegEx.IsMatch(Edit.Text, '^\d+$') then
          begin
            Error_Text.Text := 'Error: Input must contain only numbers.';
            Error_Text.Visible := True;
          end
          else
          begin
            Error_Text.Text := '';
            Error_Text.Visible := False;

          end;
        end;
      2:
        begin
          if not TRegEx.IsMatch(Edit.Text, '^[A-Za-z]+$') then
          begin
            Error_Text.Text := 'Error: Input must contain only characters.';
            Error_Text.Visible := True;
          end
          else
          begin
            Error_Text.Text := '';
            Error_Text.Visible := False;

          end;
        end;
      3:
        begin
          if not TRegEx.IsMatch(Edit.Text, '^[A-Za-z0-9]+$') then
          begin
            Error_Text.Text := 'Error: Input must contain only characters and numbers.';
            Error_Text.Visible := True;
          end
          else
          begin
            Error_Text.Text := '';
            Error_Text.Visible := False;
          end;
        end;
    end;
  end;
```

And I am calling it with ontyping event:

```
procedure TForm_Main.Edit_Code_TypeTyping(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Input(Edit_Code_Type, 1)
end;
```

This is the expected result:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F8BiK.png)

And this is the result I get instead:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NXPak.png)

I tried everything I know but so far, but I either get error message or it starts to create labels infinitely.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have `Error_Text` as a local variable within the method.  Local variables are not preserved between calls to the method, and their value is not set to any default.  So `Error_Text` may be **nil** each time the method is called, in which case your test for it being assigned will result in a new label each time, or it may be some random value, in which case you will attempt to set the text of a control that isn't valid.

Why are you creating the label at run time?  Why not create the label at design time?
You also have a lot of unnecessary code.  There is little point in hiding an empty label, as you won't see it in any case.

I'd create the label at design time, and rewrite your code to something like this:

```
procedure TForm_Main.Input(Edit: TEdit; I: Integer);
begin
  Error_Text.Text := '';
  if not Edit.Text.IsEmpty then 
  begin
    case I of
      1: if not TRegEx.IsMatch(Edit.Text, '^\d+$') 
         then Error_Text.Text := 'Error: Input must contain only numbers.';
      2: if not TRegEx.IsMatch(Edit.Text, '^[A-Za-z]+$') 
         then Error_Text.Text := 'Error: Input must contain only characters.';
      3: if not TRegEx.IsMatch(Edit.Text, '^[A-Za-z0-9]+$') 
         then Error_Text.Text := 'Error: Input must contain only characters and numbers.';
    end; {case}
  end;  {if}
end;
```